# Git - how to get all messages from commits in given range?

Tags: git

Is there any simple way to get only commit messages as plain text, without any other info in output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `git log --pretty=format:%B <from>..<to>` is what you're after.

e.g. for one of my projects:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%B 35548842b09..HEAD

Changes quoting to fix transcoding on windows

Removes an unneeded puts statement

Updates the readme

Updates streamroller.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this command:

```
git log --since --before
```

[for more info](http://gitref.org/inspect/#log)

Answer (score 0):

`git log --format=format:%b` to show only the body of the commit, or `git log --format=format:%s` for the subject, without any other info.

Comment: It should be %B instead of %b.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git log --format=%B`. Try `man git-log` for more options.